# AttributeError: module 'torch.jit' has no attribute '_script_if_tracing'

Tags: google-colaboratory

```
import detectron2
from detectron2.utils.logger import setup_logger
setup_logger()

# import some common libraries
import numpy as np
import cv2
import random
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# import some common detectron2 utilities
from detectron2 import model_zoo
from detectron2.engine import DefaultPredictor
from detectron2.config import get_cfg
from detectron2.utils.visualizer import Visualizer
from detectron2.data import MetadataCatalog
```

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-fa7489d52c2b> in <module>()
     12 # import some common detectron2 utilities
     13 
---> 14 from detectron2.engine import DefaultPredictor
     15 from detectron2.config import get_cfg
     16 from detectron2.utils.visualizer import Visualizer

15 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchvision/ops/boxes.py in <module>()
     43 
     44 
---> 45 @torch.jit._script_if_tracing
     46 def batched_nms(
     47     boxes: Tensor,

AttributeError: module 'torch.jit' has no attribute '_script_if_tracing'
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case using `pip install torchvision==0.7.0` instead of `torchvision==0.7.0+cpu` solved the error.